# Java (JVM) set CPU power

Tags: java, jvm

I want to do some measurements with Java using different methods with parallel computation, blocking, non-blocking approaches etc.

In order to guarantee that the CPU is always using its same resources, I need to assign/set CPU's power for the JVM. In this case, theoretically, the measured computation should always result identical, independently how often the same code is called.

Is there any way to set the JVM's CPU to a fixed value?

Comment: 1) Install VirutalBox. 2) Set CPU power, RAM etc. 3) profit.

Comment: Is that the only way to do? Sounds a little bit to complicated (not to build up such a system, but the workaround itself to compile and test the code)

Comment: There are no magic JVM flags for CPU availability. Of course there are plenty of ways of limiting CPU resources for a process. I just offered the simplest and most cross platform solution for a beginner to use.

Comment: Why not include some baseline in your measurements instead so you can make relative comparisons?